# Codeigniter Catagorizing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm probably over thinking this, but for the life of me I can't figure this out.

I have a list that I would like to print out, but I would like to categorize the list by state. I know I could do a bunch of queries, one for each state, but I would like to avoid that.

This is what the code looks like in my view.

```
<?foreach($tnrClinics as $row) :?>
    <h2 style="text-decoration: underline;"><?=$row->state?></h2>
    <p><?=$row->name?></p>
    <p><?=$row->address?></p>
<?endforeach;?>
```

and this is what it looks like. But instead of listing Florida over and over again I would like to have one main category of Florida and list all the clinics underneath.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Track that state changes...

```
$lastState = '';

<?foreach($tnrClinics as $row) :?>

   <php? if ($row->state !== $lastState) {
      <h2 style="text-decoration: underline;">
        <?=$row->state?>
      </h2>
      $lastState = $row->state;
    } ?> 

    <p><?=$row->name?></p>
    <p><?=$row->address?></p>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just a heads up though the php tags are a bit mis-matched.